# RCP view does not load once closed even when application is rerun

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I am new to eclipse RCP
if i close the view while application is running, the view does not load next time when I run the application. Its somewhat like the application is saving its last state and does not go back to initial state.
How do I make the application go back to initial state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your RCP to start in its original state each time it is started specify the `-clearPersistedState` option.

You can specify this in your .product file on the 'Launching' tab in 'Program Arguments' section.

Note: This option is for Eclipse 4.x

Comment: Platform UI also provides an option to reset perspective (Window menu).

Comment: @Basilevs This is a RCP which may not have the reset perspective menu